# How can I select data and get a hierarchy result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that contains categories list

**Table Structure**

```
- ID
- category_name
- parent_category_ID // 0 indicates no parent
```

**Assuming the following data is in the table**

```
ID  | category_name | parent_category_ID
1   | verbs         | 0
2   | adjectives    | 0
3   | nouns         | 0
4   | go            | 1
5   | color         | 3
6   | bag           | 3
7   | good          | 2
8   | play          | 1
9   | polite        | 2
10  | t1            | 5
11  | t2            | 5
12  | t3            | 8
```

**I want the result to be in this order**

```
ID  | category_name | parent_category_ID
1   | verbs         | 0
4   | go            | 1
8   | play          | 1
12  | t3            | 8
2   | adjectives    | 0
7   | good          | 2
9   | polite        | 2
3   | nouns         | 0
5   | color         | 3
10  | t1            | 5
11  | t2            | 5
6   | bag           | 3
```

which will make the result appear as they are like

```
verbs
--- go
--- play
--- --- t3
adjectives
--- good
--- polite
nouns
--- color
--- --- t1
--- --- t2
--- bag
```

I actually got no idea how to start doing this as my `SQL` experience is still beginner.

Comment: Mention please by which field you want to order list?

Comment: See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ or google

Comment: there is no order in your table....mention what u are trying to do!

Comment: @Sadikhasan I want the order to be first for the parent categories and the following by their children, I will edit my question and try to clearify that

Comment: [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It looks like it is what I'm looking for. As there a simple form for that? Because as I have mentioned I'm still beginner and frankly I couldn't understand most of the solution.

Comment: @Dazents the problem you are working with is little bit advance when you need to do in MySQL --

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I understood this correctly but try this:

```
SELECT 
      id, 
      category_name, 
      parent_category_ID
FROM  yourTableName
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN parent_category_ID = 0 
THEN ID 
ELSE parent_category_ID END, id
```

Demo: [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cf80/15)

Comment: That quite did it. But as you can see the last three rows (t1, t2, t3) wasn't placed under their parents category.

Comment: @Dazents check again your requirement, I have impression that you need exactly what this answer is.